# Having 2 hosting accounts in case one of downtime?

Tags: web-hosting, dns, uptime

I'm looking for a simple solution to increase my website's uptime. My website consists of simple HTML and PHP pages with no database. Right right I use paid shared hosting and I sometimes find that my website is not loading.

Would it be possible to put my website on two hosts and in case the main host is down the other one would get used? What is the best way to set this up?

Comment: If your host is constantly having down time, it's time to change hosts.

This questions has also been asked and answered on the sister site:  http://serverfault.com/questions/319697/can-i-point-my-dns-to-nameservers-of-different-web-hosts

Comment: If you are okay with getting content cached, I suggest you look at services like CloudFlare which cache content and display even though your website is down.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to go about using multiple hosts for better performance and uptime.

### Load Balancer

A [load balancer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_(computing)) accepts all connections for your website and forwards them to a pool of web servers.  The load balancer keeps track of which servers are responding and which ones are not.

### Hot Spare

A hot spare is a website that is configured and running in a different location from your current website but which is not receiving any traffic.  If your primary host goes down, you can switch DNS to point to the hot spare.  This will involve some amount of down time because DNS records have a time to live (TTL) on them.  I usually keep TTL to under an hour to enable this switch-over to happen in a reasonable amount of time.

---

If your website is running on shared hosting, neither of these may be appropriate for you.  A load balancer with two hosts behind it is going to cost at least $150/month.   A hot spare only eliminates long periods of downtime and is usually used with a load balancer in each location.

For much less than $150/month you could find a host that offers acceptable uptime.  See: [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

Answer (score 1):

No it is no possible. I would suggest you to get a better hosting plan instead of paying for two pay for one which is always on-line.