# How to dynamically change the host URL?

Tags: web-hosting, server, nameserver, load-balance

I have two websites, say `a.com` and `b.com`.

`a.com` is on a paid hosting service, and `b.com` is on 000Webhost.

000Webhost crashes sometimes, and my site `b.com` becomes unreachable.

So is there any way that I can:

1. create a copy of `b.com`, in a subfolder of `a.co`m, like `a.com/bdotcom`
2. If `b.com` is unreachable, redirect it to `a.com/bdotcom`
3. If possible, keep the url as `b.com`

Comment: [Having 2 hosting accounts in case one of downtime?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/52631/17633)

Comment: This question requires DNS management, as answered below, which is a bit different than the linked duplicate question.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to have a program checking the status of `b.com` and once it was unreachable use an API to set a `CNAME` record for `b.com` pointed to `a.com/bodtcom`, though you would need to use `b.a.com` and have it as a sub-domain.

However a host that is unreachable for me, may still be reached by others. It all depends on what the problem is and where.

In my opinion, I would leave 000Webhost, and move that domain to a more reliable hosting company.

If you have enough money the best solution is to use a load balancer and Scalr on AWS or another cloud service that can monitor your two domains and servers and if a problem comes up it would automatically re-direct traffic.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would require DNS switching.

Check with the domain hosting provider if they can switch it to your backup site as fallback requirement.